# How to make a conditional lable call in batch

Tags: batch-file

I want to make a simple batch script that should be able to run **ant build script**. When I start the batfile I want it to prompt me for target name. Then to do a simple conditional test: IF I just type enter (without entering any string) to GOTO a lable1, ELSE to GOTO the lable2 (wich calls the **ant** with argument, what I have entered at the promt). So this is what I tried with but didn't work:

```
@echo off

set /p target=Please enter target:  

IF %target%=="" (GOTO Call_script_with_default_target) ELSE (GOTO     Call_script_with_specified_target)

:Call_script_with_default_target
echo ant default-target
::when no argument is present, it assumes default target
ant 
pause
GOTO End

:Call_script_with_specified_target
echo ant %target%
ant %target%
GOTO End

:End
pause
```

When I type `clean` (at prompt) it works as expected, but when I just hit **enter** nothings happen.

Comment: try with `IF "%target%"==""`.Have on mind that `ant` is a bat file and you need it to call it like `call ant ..`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The facts:

- `set /p target=Please enter target:` command keeps value of `target` variable unchanged if user just hits <kbd>enter</kbd>;
- `%target%` evaluates to empty string if not initialised. Hence, `IF %target%=="" (...` evaluates to syntactically wrong `IF =="" (...` and raises an error.

Either use `IF "%target%"=="" (...`, or simplify your script to equivalent

```
@echo off

set "target="
set /p target=Please enter target:  

call ant %target%

:End
pause
```

Comment: LOL - we all are so focussed on eliminating errors, that we sometimes don't see the obvious... +1

Answer (score 1):

Include the quotes in BOTH sides of the test.

```
IF "%target%"=="" ...
```

Or check if the variable holds something

```
if defined target ...
```

Or detect if the `set /p` operation failed

```
set /p "target=Please enter target:"  || GOTO Call_script_with_default_target
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use "if defined variable" or "if not defined variable" as such:

```
@echo off

set /p target=Please enter target:  

 if not defined target (
  echo ant default-target
  ant 
  pause
  goto :EOF
) else (
  echo ant %target%
  ant %target%
  pause
  goto :EOF
)
```